# How to remove an attachment using JIRA soap service

Tags: jira

Reading the API I don't see any methods that can do this?

http://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/rpc-jira-plugin/latest/index.html?com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/JiraSoapService.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would need a custom SOAP plugin. Not too hard, just annoying that the method isn't there.

~Matt

Answer (score 1):

SOAP doesn't support this, but you can do it via HTTP, e.g. (C#)

```
using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    string url = "http://jira-server/secure/DeleteAttachment.jspa?id=" +
                 issue.id + "&amp;deleteAttachmentId=" + attachment_id;

    client.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    string response = client.DownloadString(url);
    // do whatever validation/reporting with the response...
}
```

You can check the url from your web browser - has to be the deletion confirmation page, not the link from the initial delete button.

Comment: Very true. Lots of other examples of this RESTful approach at http://jiradev.blogspot.com/2011/08/adding-components-to-jira-automatically.html

Comment: I am doing something similar for retrieving attachments, but i can't seem to get this to work. I have posted my problem as a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617305/how-to-remove-an-attachment-from-jira-4-4-using-http). Any help would be greatly appreciated.