# How to remove an attachment from Jira 4.4 using Http

Tags: jira

I have been looking for a way to remove an attachment from Jira using the SOAP Api, but it seems that this is not possible natively, and I would prefer not having to implement a new plugin for Jira, as suggested in the accepted answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6057411/1256868) question, or recompiling the existing plugin to support this as mentioned [here](http://www.j-tricks.com/1/post/2010/10/soap-rpc-plugin.html).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9584618/1256868) answer to the abovementioned question seems to do exactly what I want, but alas, I can't get i to work. The response i get is an error stating that:

> *XSRF Security Token Missing*
>
> *JIRA could not complete this action due to a missing form token.*
>
> *You may have cleared your browser cookies, which could have resulted in the expiry of your current form token. A new form token has been reissued.*

As I am using Asp.Net MVC C#, I have used the code from the answer, *as is*, with only the server url adjusted, as well as with different credentials (a Jira user) and the username/password passed through as request parameters using:

```
os_username=jirausername&os_password=xxxxxxx
```

The code I am currently using is as follows:

```
public void RemoveAttachment(string issueid, string attachmentid)
        {
            using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {
                //Compute jira server base url from WS url
                string baseUrl = _service.Url.Substring(0, _service.Url.IndexOf("/rpc/"));

                //Compute complete attachment url
                string attachmenturl = baseUrl + "/secure/DeleteAttachment.jspa?id=" +
                                       issueid + "&deleteAttachmentId=" + attachmentid;

                client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("jirausername", "xxxxxxx");
                string response = client.DownloadString(attachmenturl);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Did you perform a JIRA SOAP login before attempting the attachment deletion?  i.e. `jira_token = jira_object.login(username, password)`.  I'm not sure, but that might somehow create the security tokens.  Another thing to check - can you delete one such attachment using the web interface?  Some actions are restricted using JIRA permission schemes, others need admin rights....

Comment: I had already performed a login, and attempted to use the token in a couple of ways. I also have the proper permissions already. But thanks to your comment i noticed that the url of the deletion confirmation page is DeleteAttachment!default.jspa?atl_token=BSMT-K4U9-TEZ2-OYEI|a1427bcf5fd94ffb96c4634055a53a6c00af8b00|lin&id=10598&deleteAttachmentId=10602 (notice the !default.jspa part and the token) which brought me to a solution. See answer below for full explanation. Which version are you using? I think that the atl_token is relatively new...

Comment: I'm using v4.0.1#471.  Congrats on sorting it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a method that first requests the deletion confirmation form, then extracts a required token from the form, and finally posts something equivalent to the form content in order to delete the attachment. Code below.

```
public void RemoveAttachment(string issueid, string attachmentid)
{
    //Compute jira server base url from WS url
    string baseUrl = _service.Url.Substring(0, _service.Url.IndexOf("/rpc/"));

    //Compute complete attachment deletion confirm url
    string confirmurl = baseUrl + "/secure/DeleteAttachment!default.jspa?id=" +
                 issueid + "&deleteAttachmentId=" + attachmentid + "&os_username=jirauser&os_password=xxxxxx";

    //Create a cookie container to maintain the xsrf security token cookie.
    CookieContainer jiracontainer = new CookieContainer();

    //Create a get request for the page containing the delete confirmation.
    HttpWebRequest confirmrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(confirmurl);
    confirmrequest.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    confirmrequest.CookieContainer = jiracontainer;

    //Get the response and the responsestream.
    WebResponse confirmdeleteresponse = confirmrequest.GetResponse();
    Stream ReceiveStream = confirmdeleteresponse.GetResponseStream();

    // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
    StreamReader confirmreader = new StreamReader(ReceiveStream);
    // Read the content.
    string confirmresponse = confirmreader.ReadToEnd();

    //Create a regex to extract the atl/xsrf token from a hidden field. (Might be nicer to read it from a cookie, which should also be possible).
    Regex atl_token_matcher = new Regex("<input[^>]*id=\"atl_token\"[^>]*value=\"(?<token>\\S+)\"[^>]*>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
    Match token_match = atl_token_matcher.Match(confirmresponse);

    if (token_match.Success)
    {
        //If we found the token get the value.
        string token = token_match.Groups["token"].Value;

        //Compute attachment delete url.
        string deleteurl = baseUrl + "/secure/DeleteAttachment.jspa";

        //Construct form data.
        string postdata = "atl_token=" + HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(token) + "&id=" + issueid + "&deleteAttachmentId=" + attachmentid + "&Delete=Delete&os_username=jirauser&os_password=xxxxxx";

        //Create a post request for the deletion page.
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(deleteurl);
        request.KeepAlive = false;
        request.CookieContainer = jiracontainer; // Remember to set the cookiecontainer.
        request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
        request.Method = "POST";

        //Turn our request string into a byte stream
        byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postdata);

        //Make sure you specify the proper type.
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

        //Send the post.
        requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        //Get the response.
        WebResponse deleteresponse = request.GetResponse();

        // Open the responsestream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader deleteresponsereader = new StreamReader(deleteresponse.GetResponseStream());

        // Read the content.
        string deleteresponsecontent = deleteresponsereader.ReadToEnd();

        // do whatever validation/reporting with the response...
    }
    else
    {
        //We couldn't find the atl_token. Throw an error or something...
    }

}
```

Edit:
Same thing works for removing comments. Replace 'attachment' with 'comment' and 'deleteAttachmentId' with 'commentId' and you should be good to go.